# Is it possible defines rules about groups in Plone?

Tags: plone

When I go in "Zope Management Interface" > "Security" I can set permissions for users.
Can I do the same for groups?
There is a method or a plugin for this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't (set permissions for users); that tab sets permissions for *roles*; see [Permissions and roles](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/understanding-permissions/permissions-and-roles) in the "Understanding permissions" manual.

You *can* assign roles to individual users and groups.

Comment: Well, I've read that page. I know is possible assign roles to groups, but I don't know how. I can create a group, but i cannot find the right tab to set the roles like users.

Comment: @user840718: the control panel for users and groups let's you assign roles; see http://plone.org/products/plone/features/more-powerful-management-of-users-and-groups

Comment: Well now I've understood the problem.
I've almost solved the problem, one last thing.
I've created 3 groups (A B C), each one with 1 user, each one with "contributor" users, it's more simply for an example.
My final question is: I have this situation, is it possible customize the contributor role for each group?
In the end, the users of group A despite are "contributor" like group B and C, can do different action from B and C.
Is it possible?

Comment: @user840718: No, roles are not 'customizable' per group. Generally you want to use 'local roles' and/or workflows for most complex permission usecases.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to map permissions to roles via the "Security" tab in the ZMI.  You should instead create workflows (ZMI-->portal_workflow) and customize permissions through it.

In your workflow, you need to define states and transitions.  And within each state, you can manage what permissions to give to specific roles.  If you need to, you can also map groups to roles.

After customizing your workflow, you then assign it to specific content types (in portal_workflow).

Don't forget to run "update security" so that your new workflow will be applied to existing content.

Comment: This is because workflow states map permissions to roles (the same thing you would do on the "Security" tab), so if the workflow state changes, it will override any manual settings you may have done via the "Security" tab. 

The "Security" tab is OK for quickly troubleshooting something, but once you know what you want, you should do it properly in terms of workflow.